# Doctrine QueryBuilder - Struggling with table 'state' variable

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have the following query and the last part of it is to check the state of the item which will be 1 or 0;

> My api calls:
>   http://example.com/api/search?keyword=someword&search_for=item&return_product

The query works as expected, except for one thing. Some of the stone items are disabled and I need to ignore where:

```
  ->where('S.state=:state')
  ->setParameter('state' , 1 )
```

I am not quite sure where to add this to the current query to get it to work:

```
$qb = $this->stoneRepository->createQueryBuilder('S');

//Get the image for the item
$qb->addSelect('I')
->leftJoin('S.image' , 'I');

//Check if we want products returned
if ( $return_product )
{
      $qb->addSelect('P','PI')
      ->leftJoin('S.product'   , 'P')
      ->leftJoin('P.image'     , 'PI');
 }

 //Check is we want attributes returned
 if ( $return_attribute )
 {
     $qb->addSelect('A','C')
     ->leftJoin('S.attribute' , 'A')
     ->leftJoin('A.category'  , 'C');
 }

//Check the fields for matches
$qb->add('where' , $qb->expr()->orX(
          $qb->expr()->like('S.name' , ':keyword'),
          $qb->expr()->like('S.description' , ':keyword')
        )
);

//Set the search item
$qb->setParameter('keyword', '%'.$keyword.'%');
$qb->add('orderBy', 'S.name ASC');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after the `createQueryBuilder` call:

```
$qb = $this->stoneRepository
    ->createQueryBuilder('S')
    ->where('S.state = :state')
    ->setParameter('state', 1);
```

With the query builder the order is not important: you can add SQL pieces in different order and even override pieces already added.